# C++ std::string compare with abbreviations

Tags: c++

Let's say I have read a C++ std::string, *mystring*, in from *std::cin* thus:

```
std::cin  >>  mystring;
```

Now I'd like to see if *mystring* is any substring of *std::masterStr* with at least *len* characters matching.

In Rexx id say

```
abbrev( mystring, masterStr, len ).
```

How do I code it in C++?

Comment: What is your definition of "substring" here?  Do you mean that you want to identify any length-`len` substring of `mystring` that is also a substring of `masterStr`?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question: do you mean that you want to check whether the `len` first characters of `mystring` exist somewhere in `masterStr` ? Or is it *any* substring of `len` characters in `mystring` that you are searching for ?

Comment: [This](http://www.kilowattsoftware.com/tutorial/rexx/biabbrev.htm) for more info?

Comment: According to Rapptz's link, `abbrev` doesn't check for any substring but only for a prefix. Which do you need?

Comment: I think the clue was in the name.

Comment: @Rapptz gets +1 not only for looking at the Rexx syntax, but for pointing out to me that I had the syntax backward.  Its abbrev( masterStr, mayBeAbbrevStr, len )

Comment: To answer all the questions,  `result = Abbrev( information, info [, length ] ] )` _The Abbrev function determines whether one string_ info _is a leading substring of another string_ information. _An optional minimum_ length _can be specified. The function returns 1 when the test string is a leading abbreviation of the reference string, and 0 otherwise. If the test string is shorter than the minimal length, then 0 is returned._

Comment: I never thought an abbreviation would imply anything but a leading string.  In natural language, i.e. English, here, an abbreviation alwasy starts with the front _len_ letters of the abbreviated word.  Not to be confused with acronyms which may contain any subset of lettes in the word _or phrase_.

Comment: If you mean a prefix only then don't say "any substring". And in English "abbreviation" doesn't necessarily refer to the initial letters, e.g. Dr is an abbreviation of doctor.

Comment: Touche.  +1 for @interjay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like the following do the trick:

```
bool
isAbbrev( std::string const& toTest, std::string const& master, int minLength )
{
    return toTest.size() >= minLength
        && toTest.size() <= master.size()
        && std::equal( toTest.begin(), toTest.end(), master.begin() ) ;
}
```

This finds a match at the start, like the function in Rexx.  If
you want to find a match anywhere:

```
bool
isAbbrev( std::string const& toTest, std::string const& master, int minLength )
{
    return toTest.size() >= minLength
        && std::search( master.begin(), master.end(),
                        toTest.begin(), toTest.end() )
                != master.end();
}
```

should do the trick.